# how can I define static var in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static

I know this code must be so simple. But I couldn't understand it well.

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

I know `public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE` define an static var.

But what is "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"?

code is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?).

Comment: It is the value of the string literal that you have successfully defined as a static variable, which makes it entirely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: People would have less of a problem understanding if you explained what EXTRA_MESSAGE is used for. Only linking to it is considered bad practice on SO. I suspect it is an identifier for an intent but I'm not familiar with android programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just some text that passed to another activity....it's just an example

In the tutorial they want to show that how to send an extra message to another activity.

You can do it by put an extra message with `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);` and then in another activity, you can catch it with `String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);`

`EXTRA_MESSAGE` here is some label or key to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`EXTRA_MESSAGE` is declared as `string` so, it is a string type `variable` which can hold string

So it could also be like

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "any string or text here";
```

Answer (score 0):

**EXTRA_MESSAGE** is a **key** used to pass a `string` via an Intent.
For example:

```
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
    String strName = null;
    i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", strName);

    //Then, to retrieve the value try something like:

    String newString;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
    }
    } else {
      newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
    }
```